# CSS - background always displays behind <img>

Tags: css

Please see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gpvqjv0b/) fiddle.

I want to display an element on top of an image and have its background cover the image, so that it looks like this:

```
 ------
|      |
|  12  |-------
|      |       |
 ------        |
   |           |
   |           |
    -----------
```

and not this:

```
 ------
|      |
|  12----------
|  |           |
 --|           |
   |           |
   |           |
    -----------
```

The idea is a user image and a number of notifications. I do not want to use another image for the background of the notifications box.

I had thought that the notifications coming after the img in the markup would make it display above the image but alas not.

Changing the z-index has no effect (this was my first thought), but I rather to use the flow of the markup to achieve layering anyway as z-index i find less maintainable (so I'm kind of glad it didn't work).

But I cannot solve the problem... What is a workable solution?

Comment: When you add z-index, you add position:relative too?

Comment: add `position: relative;` to `#num`, this should solve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to `#num`, so it will 'flow' above the other elements.

[Check the update Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpvqjv0b/4/).

Comment: Every answer was valid but this was concise and also addressed the issue of 'flow' of the markup which is what I bare in mind when writing it (and I can only accept one answer). Thanks to all. The `position` allowing z-index to take effect was new to me.

Answer (score 2):

In order for z-index to work the element on which is applied must have a positioning, in your case that should be relative, so just add: `position: relative; z-index: 1;` for the #num

Here's the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpvqjv0b/1/)

Comment: There is actually no need to add the z-index. `position: relative;` on its own solves the issue (which is good as I don't like using z-index). I can live with `position: relative;`

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/gpvqjv0b/2/

Z index only works on positioned elements

```
#num {
display: block;
width: 40px;
height: 30px;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
background-color: #f00;
position:absolute;
margin-left:-20px;
margin-top: 5px;
z-index:955;
```

}

Comment: Actually z-index works with any kind of positioning, just give it a try

Answer (score 1):

How about this? It uses absolute positioning for the notifications so that they are taken out of the document flow, and doesn't need any negative margins.

```
#container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 120px;
    position:relative;
}

#img {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#num {
    left:-20px;
    position:absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vursdua4/

Comment: Whilst this is a valid solution I dislike the fact that it requires making changes to the `#container` to have an effect on `#num` which is why I chose to use negative margins int eh first place. The reason is because the container is actually part of a set of divs and I want to avoid specific css for individuals in the group.

Comment: Here you go, now with no changes to `#container`: https://jsfiddle.net/vursdua4/1/

Comment: :) I also dislike adding extra markup simply for styling. I do have one exception which is for `clear: both;` but it doesn't mean I like it. Thanks for your input, I'm certain that your solution would be the way to go for most people but I prefer negative margins :)